# Push Notification in macOS/OSX app distributed outside app store

Tags: macos, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, macos-sierra, mac-app-store

I am new to developing macOS app. I need to confgure push notifications on a MacOS app which has not been distributed through app store.

I found links on apple website which suggest that apps need NOT be submitted to app store to use PUSH service if it has been signed using developer ID.
Here are the links:

1. https://developer.apple.com/macos/distribution/
   Scroll down to "Outside the Mac App Store" section --> "Integrate App Capabilities".
   Push notification is clearly stated!
2. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SupportedCapabilities/SupportedCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH38-SW1
   This link also shows push notification available in "MacDeveloper ID"

But whenever I try to archive and export my app using developer id it says:

> An error occurred.
>   The archived application has entitlements that require Mac App Store distribution.  The invalid entitlements were: com.apple.developer.aps-environment.

Does Push notification really work for Mac apps distributed outside app store? If yes, then how?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Apple Technical support, it worked successfully with Xcode 8.3+